# Why is there no Iterable in the bases of the range class but its object is Iterable instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If the object is an instance of a class, then the class should be found in the inheritance relationship of the class.

I didn't find it.In the following code, you can see clearly that in the tuple of the base class, there are only a object of class'object', and nothing else.

Is my understanding wrong?

```
rangeObject = range(3)
rangeClass = type(rangeObject)
class range(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bases_of_range(self):
        self.assertEqual(rangeClass.__bases__,(object,))
    def test_range_instance(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(rangeObject,collections.Iterable)
```

Comment: You haven't shown us any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range` is registered as a "virtual subclass" of `Sequence` (which is a subclass of `Iterable`) via [`ABC.register`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register) in order for `isinstance` or `issubclass` to work; its not actually a real subclass of Iterable.

You can see it in the [Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/35715d1e72b7e15e337087863c75af447199e0fb/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L1030).

This also applies for most of the other builtin collections.